# Android pm command throwing transactiontoolargeexception

Tags: stock-android

I am using rooted android phone and have installed AIDE for android. I am doing tutorial lessons in the app. When I click run app in any tutorials, it says "Starting… " and after few seconds "App not installed error". I looked at the superuser app's log for AIDE, and it says "unable to access package manager". Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Edit: I tried `pm` command in terminal emulator app with su access, it shows same error: "package manager not running…" I guess there is a problem with the `pm` command. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your version of the su binary. I was using ChainFire's updated binary and it didn't work. I re-rooted with Kingoroot and it's now working.